# StackPanels going side by side

Tags: wpf

I have this small stackpanel that gathers information from a class I have. I want the stack panels to go side by side instead of just stacking up on top of each other. This is the code I have

```
<SplitView.Content>
            <Grid>
                <ListView x:Name ="View">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding location}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding desc}"></TextBlock>
                                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE109;"></Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Content>
```

I don't want them to go infinitly to the side though, just like 2 next to each other and then another 2 bellow, if that is possible

Answer (score 1):

You can set `ListView.ItemsPanel` to a `StackPanel` with Horizontal Orientation.

```
    <ListView x:Name ="View">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: It throws an exception if I try to use your method (first time working with c# in case)

Comment: But that is letting them go to infinity width. I would suggest using Wrappanel in the ItemsPanelTemplate instead.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned Im working in visual studio 2015 and according to it Wrappanel is not supported in a Windows app